# How to generate features to test different implementations of LinearRing?

Tags: postgis, geoserver, geometry, java

I have some code that throws the following exception:

```
Points of LinearRing do not form a closed linestring
```

and I want to check if my code is calling this correctly by supplying some features that either violate or do not violate the constraints of
[LinearRing.validateConstruction](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.vividsolutions/jts/1.11/com/vividsolutions/jts/geom/LinearRing.java#LinearRing.validateConstruction%28%29). Is there an existing Java utility that can be used to generate appropriate feature data for this?

Comment: Could you post some tidbits of your code? It is difficult to diagnose these things without knowing more about the context of the issue.

Comment: @Conor I am using http://www.vividsolutions.com/JTS/JTSHome.htm , specifically this bit http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.vividsolutions/jts/1.11/com/vividsolutions/jts/geom/LinearRing.java#LinearRing.validateConstruction%28%29

Comment: To try and clarify your question for other users, I have significantly edited your post title and body. If you feel that I have not captured the essence of your question accordingly, please make more appropriate edits to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote my own for the simplest case :

```
private static Polygon getLinearRing(int n) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>(n); //just a rnadom above 4
        Point firstPoint = RandomDataFactory.getSingle(Point.class);
        Point lastPoint = firstPoint;
        points.add(0, firstPoint);

        for (int i = 1; i < (n - 1); i++) {
            points.add(i, RandomDataFactory.getSingle(Point.class));
        }
        points.add(n - 1, lastPoint);

        Polygon linearRing = new Polygon(points);
        return linearRing;
    }
```

where RandomDataFactory looks like [this](http://pastebin.com/EaNDCHGR)